# Filemaker: List View: Different UI for each record

Tags: user-interface, filemaker

I am using the List View. Based on variables I want to display different groups of objects (buttons, text etc.) in different records (shown at the same time).

My first attempt for a solution was to use tabs that I control via scripts. The problem is, that all records in the list view always display the same tab
of a tab control. So if I go to one tab in a records all other records also go to this tab.

Unfortunatly there is also no hide option that allows to hide groups of objects.

Is there any solution? I have filemaker 11 and 12. Altough a solution for filemaker 11 would be prefered.

Thank you!

Comment: I workaround can be found here: http://www.filemakertoday.com/com/showthread.php/30923-List-View-Different-UI-for-each-record?p=125160&posted=1#post125160

Answer (score 0):

No. You can do this in form view (hidden tabs and a trigger) or in a report (sliding elements surrounded by portals), but not in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. The way you say can not be done as far as I know.

What you can do to hide the fields is using some other element on top of it with "conditional formatting" so that it can be hidden.